# How do I declare an instance variable that I will use in all of my actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this declaration that I want to use in all of my actions in my `NewsroomController`, how do I do this in a DRY way, rather than declaring it in each action?

```
@num_posts_today = Post.published.posted_today.count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the logic in the model. Something like:

```
def posts_published_today_count
  self.published.posted_today.count
end
```

Or write a class method.

```
def self.published_today
  self.published.posted_today
end
```

In your controller:

```
Post.published_today.count
```

Or in views:

```
@posts.published_today.count
```

You get the idea... I didn't test what I wrote, feel free to make modifications.

I prefer writing it without .count on my model and you can use that as a scope incase you need to use in the future.

Comment: This is definitely a good way to do it. However, it won't make the variable available to the view, as I suspect OP wants. I also think it won't cache by default, so if you use it twice it'll ask the database twice.

Comment: You should be be able to access it in views, write a class method, see edits

Comment: Yeh I much prefer this too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a `before_action` block. However, read [this](http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2014/02/before_action_an_anti_pattern/) for why it might not be awesome.

Comment: Is there a more Rails 4 way to do it?

Comment: It is not inherently good, not inherently bad. If you really need to do it in all actions, I'd say go for it. If you start getting exceptions, then I'd prefer doing it the non-DRY way, adopting @neo's method and using something like `@num_posts_today = posts_published_today_count` at the top of the actions that need it. The article spells out the pros and the cons; it is up to you to weigh them.